# How long does a small update take?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I might have a new app ready in a couple of days so I'm not sure if I should use the slot available right now to update my old app. I want to get the new app in the store asap.

How long does it take usually for small updates like graphic changes or just simply changing the name of your app?

Comment: this question is off topic as it is about speculative information on internal Apple review processes.

Answer (score 1):

All updates, small or large will go thru the same review process. An update to an app can take anywhere between 3 to 6 days. But I've had an update that took 4 weeks. you just never know.

If you go to the [App Store Approval Process](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/index.html) page you will see that 99% of all updatw will be revied within 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a simple update takes 2-3 days..but not sure may take upto 10-15 days.